# How to make override abstract method in dart or flutter

Tags: dart

My background is from java, so i can implement abstract classes and methods in java like given bellow:

**Class 1**

```
public class Base {

  public void method( VerificationCallbacks verificationCallbacks){

       verificationCallbacks.signInWithEmail();

    };
}
```

**Abstract class**

```
public abstract class VerificationCallbacks {

    public abstract void signInWithEmail();

    public abstract void signUpInWithEmail();
}
```

**so we can implement these classes like**

```
     Base base = new Base();
      base.method(new VerificationCallbacks() {
        @Override
        public void signInWithEmail() {

        }

        @Override
        public void signUpInWithEmail() {

        }
    });
```

But now i want to implement this technique in dart or flutter

```
 Base base = new Base();

 base.method(new VerificationCallbacks());
```

but when i write this code to implement override methods, it shows **abstract classes cannot be instantiated dart**, please anyone can help me to achieve this.

Comment: Create a subclass, and instantiate that.

Comment: Please can you give me more explanation or example, actually i want callbacks in case of any action.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Comment: java is working fine for me, but i want same technique in dart.

Comment: You mean to say that this code: base.method(new VerificationCallbacks()); works for you in Java? call me a skeptic, I'm not buying it.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Base {
  void method({
    VoidCallback signInWithEmailCallback,
    VoidCallback signUpWithEmailCallback,
  }) {
    if (true) {
      signInWithEmailCallback();
    } else {
      signUpWithEmailCallback();
    }
  }
}
```

and

```
Base base = Base();
base.method(signInWithEmailCallback: () {
  //
}, signUpWithEmailCallback: () {
  //
});
```

also you can define you own alias for callback like this

```
typedef VerificationCallback = void Function();
```

and use it

```
class Base {
  void method({
    VerificationCallback signInWithEmailCallback,
    VerificationCallback signUpWithEmailCallback,
  }) {
    // logic here
  }
}
```